# IJCADでサムネイル画像を作成すると、サムネイルのモデル空間の背景色が白色になってしまう。

Tags: c#, .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2018を使用して、C#で開発を行っております。

図面保存時に現在のビューでサムネイル画像を保存したいのですが、背景の色が「IJCADで設定した背景色」ではなく、白色になってしまいます。
サムネイルの背景色を「IJCADで設定した背景色」へ適用する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「IJCADで設定した背景色」とはIJCAD設定画面の赤枠で囲んだ箇所となります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
using CADApplication = GrxCAD.ApplicationServices.Application;
using GrxCAD.Runtime;
using System.Reflection;
namespace Iest
{
   public class CreateThumbnail
   {
       [CommandMethod("Test_CreateThumbnail", CommandFlags.Session)]
       public static void Test()
       {
           var doc = CADApplication.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
           var ed = doc.Editor;
           var db = doc.Database;

           // 拡大
           ZoomAll();
           ed.Regen();
           ed.UpdateScreen();

           // プレビュー作成
           var sz = CADApplication.MainWindow.DeviceIndependentSize;
           var dHheight = sz.Height;
           var dWidth   = sz.Width;
           double rx = 300.0 / dWidth;
           uint height = (uint)(dHheight * rx);
           uint width  = (uint)(dWidth * rx);
           // ↓プレビュー画像を作成すると背景が白色になってしまう
           db.ThumbnailBitmap = doc.CapturePreviewImage(width, height);

           // 上書き保存
           db.Save();
       }

       public static void ZoomAll()
       {
           var acadObject = CADApplication.AcadApplication;
           acadObject.GetType().InvokeMember("ZoomExtents", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, acadObject, null);
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: 質問は「白色以外の任意の色を設定したい」で合っていますか？念のため、画像形式がBMP(ビットマップ)だと背景色を透過には出来ないと思います。

Comment: 質問は「白色以外の任意の色を設定したい」で合っています。
背景色ですがBMPの背景色ではなく、IJCADのアプリケーションから設定できるモデル空間の背景色となります。
質問内容の背景色に語弊がありましたので修正を行いました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DWGファイルのプレビューサムネイルは図面の保存時に作成されます。

AutoCADではAutoCAD2013からサムネイルの背景色を、作図空間の背景色と同じ色になるように変更されたようですが、IJCADではAutoCAD2013以前と同じ仕様で背景色を白色にしているのだと思われます。